# Problemas con el while insert en sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

como podría hacer un while para que me registre esos 4 resultados que vienen de un parametros con valores y lo demás que vienen sin valores me salga null, veo ejemplos pero no logro el resultado, más adelante lo tengo que hacer con parámetros. Ayuda por favor

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba3
(
    C1 INT NULL,
    C2 INT NULL,
    C3 INT NULL,
    C4 INT NULL,
    C5 INT NULL,
    C6 INT NULL,
    C7 INT NULL,
    C8 INT NULL,
    C9 INT NULL,
    C10 INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Prueba3 (C1,C2,C3,C4) VALUES ('55', '55', '55', '55')

SELECT * FROM Prueba3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es algo sencillo, pero espero que te funcione:
"Bandera" es la cantidad de columnas a insertar.
"Valor" son los datos a insertar
"Cont" es un auxiliar para el while

```
CREATE TABLE #Prueba3
(
    C1 INT NULL,
    C2 INT NULL,
    C3 INT NULL,
    C4 INT NULL,
    C5 INT NULL,
    C6 INT NULL,
    C7 INT NULL,
    C8 INT NULL,
    C9 INT NULL,
    C10 INT NULL
)

declare @bandera int =4
,@valor int =55
,@Cont int =2
declare @query nvarchar(500)
,@query2 nvarchar(500)
,@aux varchar(5)


    set @query='insert into #Prueba3(C1,'
    set @query2='values ('+cast(@valor as varchar(10))+','
while @Cont<=@bandera
begin
    if (@Cont=@bandera)
        set @aux=')'
    else
        set @aux=','

    set @query+='C'+cast(@Cont as nvarchar(10))+@aux
    set @query2+=cast(@valor as varchar(10))+@aux
    set @Cont+=1
end

set @query+=' '+@query2
print @query

execute sp_executesql @query

select * from #Prueba3

drop table #Prueba3
```